# Oracle get intersection of the views

Tags: sql, oracle

I created views by `CREATE VIEW lalala AS SELECT * FROM lalalala` and I have two different views. How can I intersect them? `view1 intersect view2` doesn't work.

Comment: "*doesn't work*" isn't a valid Oracle error message. And intersect sure does work in Oracle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c6ec8/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you might be misunderstanding the purpose of a view. A view is a sort of "derived" table, whose data depends on the data in (usually) one or more other tables. You still `SELECT` from it in the same way as a normal table. So, for example, if you have this:

```
CREATE VIEW lalala AS SELECT * FROM lalalala;
```

then you would query this view by writing:

```
SELECT * FROM lalala WHERE ...;
```

. . . which means that this view is, most likely, not useful; aside from questions of privileges and ownership and so on, `lalala` is equivalent to `lalalala`.

To compute the intersection of two views, you would write:

```
SELECT * FROM view1
INTERSECT
SELECT * FROM view2
```

Answer (score 0):

`INNER JOIN` them on each other.